# How to do POST API in flutter using Dio ,retrofit and riverpod?

Tags: flutter, api, http-post, retrofit, riverpod

Can someone help me with the POST API request in flutter using dio, riverpod and retrofit , its quite confusing. It will be very helpful if someone explain the whole flow with code

Im not sure about the code, can someone help with thee code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Riverpod 2.x

```dart
@riverpod
Future<MyModel> httpGet(HttpGetRef ref, String url) async {
    return await _doGet(url); 
}

Future<MyModel> _doGet(String url) async {
     // use whatever lib for HTTP
    // get the response and deserialize
   return deserialized;
}
```

now in a `ConsumerWidget` build method, you can

```dart
final responseFuture = ref.watch(httpGetProvider(url).future);

return Column(children: [
    FutureBuilder<MyModel>(
        future: responseFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return LoadingWidget();
            return DisplayDataWidget(data:snapshot.data!);
        }),

    Button(
        text: "Refresh", 
        onClick: () => ref.invalidate(httpGetProvider(url))
    )
    ]);
```

Depending on your app, you may want to wrap the provider in another provider, like .. say `accountInfoProvider` so your widgets don't have to know the url. You can also decide to implement caching .etc. in a provider in the middle as well.